# Windows 11 BSOD after installing Visual Studio - have bootable drive settings been changed somehow?

Tags: boot, windows-11, bsod, visual-studio, bootable-media

I installed Visual Studio from Microsoft via [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/latest-supported-vc-redist?view=msvc-170#visual-studio-2015-2017-2019-and-2022). I was wanting to install qView (minimalist image viewer), and it requires Visual Studio, so I thought I would make sure that I have the latest version. I downloaded and installed it, and immediately upon restarting, I was hit with BSOD, with the error message "BAD_POOL_HEADER".

Looking this up, I found suggestions for it being a RAM problem. OK; so I removed and reinstalled the RAM. I ran Microsoft's memory check. I used diskpart and bcdboot to check the drives and repair the boot partition. I ran chkdsk, and found no errors. But I couldn't get past the BSOD with any suggestion I tried. I couldn't get in to Safe Mode or Recovery Mode. I did manage to do a system restore to a day before installing Visual Studio - no difference, no improvement, just the BSOD looping forever. Same when I did a restore point for another week earlier.

On another suggestion, I removed my additional storage drives (I have 2, drives D and F). Now, one of them does have a copy of an old Windows installation that I kept as a backup, just in case. But it's not bootable, and I've been using the hardware/software combination for months with no issues at all. I also removed a second SSD drive with an old Windows 10 installation on it that I was going to wipe and install Linux on at some point. That drive is bootable, but Windows was at no point trying to boot that drive. When I forced it to through UEFI settings, it booted into with no problems, albeit without the storage drives connected.

After removing the 3 drives, I was able to boot in to my system on the C drive as normal. So I went back and reattached the first storage drive; no good, back to BSOD. Same with the second storge drive, same with both at the same time. Remove them again, and my C drive works as normal. The second SSD with the old Windows installation was not involved, sat on the desk the whole time.

I did notice during all this that my C drive and F drive had been swapped when I look at them with diskpart. I couldn't find out if this was a feature of Windows 11 trying to go through some sort of error-checking off the back of the BSOD, or if something else had caused it.

I believe installing Visual Studio caused it. Nothing else on my system had changed, nothing else was running, nothing else was installed. After installing it and rebooting, the problems started. The joke was, I think I already had the latest Visual Studio installed. I just thought there would be no harm making sure I had the newest version...

So I went to Microsoft Support and explained it all to them. Of course, I was gaslit with the wonderful response that I "should have contacted customer support before installing Visual Studio to check that it was compatible with [my] hardware", and the even better "this is a hardware error, there is nothing wrong with Visual Studio" - with no further investigation whatsoever. No interest in doing anything except booting into Safe Mode, which I can only do with the storage drives removed. So now after escalating this, I'm waiting for an e-mail response from Microsoft that I already know will simply advise me to do a clean install of Windows. And of course, I could work this out for myself.

I *really* don't want to do a clean install, because my music software includes hundreds of VSTs and bit and pieces that will take days to reinstall. It will be incredibly painful. And also, I figured someone else might end up going through a similar dillema.

Windows 11 has been running fine since building the PC 6 months ago. No real problems at all, just the usual minor niggles and nuisances, mostly just frustrations with Windows 11. I'd installed a lot of software, from Ableton Live to Steam games, video editing, lots of professional audio software - all without a hitch. I've built about 6 PCs over the years. I'm not a professional, but I go heavily into research to make sure everything's compatible, I test my installation thoroughly before installing more programs, and I've never had a single problem with anything I've built. I'm certainly not flawless, but I am 100% confident that hardware is not the cause of this particular problem.

However, I'm not adamant that the problem is Visual Studio, either; there could be something else corrupted that installing Visual Studio merely set off, or it could be an amazing coincidence.

But here, finally, are my questions: is there some sort of setting that has been altered, somehow, that I can change? Where does Windows 11 put its information about bootable drives, and can this be altered?

I changed the motherboard's UEFI boot settings so that it would only boot into the correct Windows drive; Windows ignored this, and gave the BSOD whenever the storage drives were connected. How can the storage drives be affecting boot in this manner? What am I missing, other than the marbles that I started the day with?

Apologies for such a long post; I couldn't work out how to make it shorter without missing vital information. And I feel I've still not provided enough!

Comment: 'Header' is the tool that ensures that the Windows API (application programming interface) is properly addressed. BAD POOL HEADER error message is a signal that your PC is having memory management issues. The memory issues can be software or hardware-related.     ....   Run Memtest86.exe to test memory.

Comment: I agree. This most likely is a hardware problem. The Boot Configuration Data (BCD) is where all versions of Windows stores the information you seek. However, Visual Stud, wouldn’t and couldn’t have changed this information

Comment: To help you diagnose this issue we unfortunately need the  analysis of WinDBG which will difficult to provide since Windows isn’t bootable

Comment: Visual Studio has nothing to do with this other than the fact that it might be accessing a feature of a driver or the kernel.  User mode applications (which this is) can not cause a BSOD in a protected mode operating system.  Only the kernel can BSOD which is almost 100% caused by a driver or hardware failure.

Comment: Thanks for all the replies. I don't think I made it clear enough, but I can boot into the system fine when storage drives are disconnected, which is why I doubt it's a hardware or RAM error.

John - I'll try and run Memtest86 later and see if reports differently to Microsoft's built in memory test. 

Ramhound - I can't install WinDBG yet; it seems it needs an appinstaller that I don't have. I'll look at that later.

Señor CMasMas - How can I check if it's a driver failure? Is there a way to check which driver could have caused the problems?

Comment: Hmm, reading back through this and thinking further, I guess my question should have been "Why will Windows 11 boot fine with no storage drives connected, but I get BSOD when I connect drives that were previously fine?" - or something like that. Should I delete and re-post?

Comment: I found that now almost any external USB hard drive (not USB sticks) will trigger a BSOD, regardless of where they're plugged in. I ran memtestx86 overnight, and the RAM passed with zero errors. I've tested the PSU and run checks on the CPU, the GPU and motherboard. No problems reported with any aspect of the hardware. I'm on the verge of reinstalling Windows 11, but, now I've backed up 4TB of storage drives, I'm first going to run Live USBs of Windows 11 and Debian and see if the problems persist...

Comment: Oh, and @Ramhound, I can't install WinDMG; App Installer comes up with an error message that says "No such interface supported".  It seems App Installer was disabled by Microsoft due to malware threats last year. There doesn't appear to be another way to get WinDMG. Would Event Viewer or Reliability Monitor outputs be any use?

Comment: As suspected, when using a Debian Live USB I get zero problems with external USB drives or anything else. I don't know what else to do to ensure this is not a hardware issue! So I'm still assuming there is a corrupt file somewhere that could probably be altered or deleted to fix the problem. Windows restore points and troubleshooting tests did nothing. Microsoft support was an absolute joke. I will do one last round of research using Event Viewer/Reliability Monitor, then do a clean reinstall. I really just don't want this to happen again.

Comment: @euchriduk - Microsoft support was a joke because they don’t actually provide support to end users.

Comment: @Ramhound They could have saved themselves an hour an 10 minutes of wasted time by acknowledging that at the beginning of the webchat!

Answer (score 0):

Finally worked out the answer myself! I hope this helps others:

The culprit was a faulty driver. I was able to trace it by going into Minidump (C:\Windows\Minidump) and reading the contents via [Blue Screen View](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/blue_screen_view.html#DownloadLinks). The crash list that the program produced reported that the driver 'mrcbt.sys' was at fault. Googling "mrcbt.sys BSOD" led me to a forum for Macrium Reflect, which I had installed and hung on to in case I needed it. I uninstalled it through Control Panel, the driver was deleted, and the BSOD problems disappeared immediately after reboot! External USB drives work as normal, internal drives are fine.

I suggest that what happened to me was that Visual Studio's installation was corrupted by or somehow corrupted Macrium Reflect, and in turn the 'mrcbt.sys' driver became corrupted. Of course, it *could* be a coincidence, and Macrium Reflect's driver could have just happened to get corrupted at the same time.

Many thanks to the others here who offered help.

No thanks at all to Microsoft Support, who were utterly useless. I wasted an hour and 10 minutes in webchat to be gaslit and insulted and ignored. The person had no idea what they were talking about, and were clearly just repeating answers from a script or algorithm. At no point did the support agent suggest using Event Viewer, Reliability Monitor or accessing or uploading Minidump files or any other kind of logs - all tools that are part of a standard Windows 11 Pro installation (and probably Home as well, I presume). I have sent in a long e-mail of complaint...

My suggestion for anyone with similar BSOD errors where you are *sure* that it's not hardware is to check Minidump first. I don't know how you view the files without Blue Screen View, but I found that the program worked great, and was very simple to use. If the answers aren't obvious from there, I would use Event Viewer and Reliability Monitor next, to at least find error codes and information you can Google. If you can't log in to your PC/laptop, I would test it with a Live Linux USB if you can, as that helped me a lot (for one things it helps confirm if your hardware is at fault or not). From the live Linux USB, I would then also access Windows report logs like Minidump and see what you can find, then, armed with information, ask for help on a forum before bothering with Microsoft Support!

My difficulty was that, not having dealt with such a drastic system error before, I did not know where to look for answers. I thought I'd post as much information as possible here to help others in the similar situations!

Comment: What’s more likely is the known issue with Macrium Reflect came into play, which I found during my research and wanted to confirm was the issue, by looking at the analysis output of WinDBG. Within 5 minutes I suspected Macrium Reflect but it’s not exactly a program everyone has so I wanted more verbose information before I said something

Comment: Thanks, @Ramhound; I take it you have a related or similar issue, then? What is the known issue with Macrium Reflect? The driver or something else? Is the output of WinDBG comparable to Minidump, Event View, etc.?

Comment: No, I don’t have any issues, I researched the problem for you and thus the reason I suggested WinDBG to debug the problem.